# How to read from a text file which does not have consisted data?

Tags: c#, datagridview, text-files

I have a text file which stores information about the production information and process. The process consists of several phases such as `Stripping`, `Cleaning`, `Paint` etc. These phases are stored with dates which could be `expected date`, `start date`, `finished date`, `delay date`.

An example .txt file:

> 567,Eindhoven,21,Stripping_e=20/05/2020,Stripping_s=21/05/2020,Stripping_f=22/05/2020,Cleaning_e=23/05/2020,Cleaning_s=27/05/2020,Cleaning_f=28/05/2020,Paint_e=28/05/2020,Panint_s=28/05/2020,Paint_f=29/05/2020,Cabinet_e=29/05/2020,Cabinet_s=31/05/2020,Cabinet_f=,Table_e=,Table_s=,Table_f=,Stand_e=,Stand_s=,Stand_f=,Display_e=,Display_s=,Display_f=,UControls_e=,UControls_s=,UControls_f=,Test_e=,Test_s=,Test_f=,Prepack_e=,Prepack_s=,Prepack_f=,Endpack_e=,Endpack_s=,Endpack_f=,Release_e=,Release_s=,Release_f=,

After I read this .txt file, I store it inside a dataGridView like:
[image]

However, I do not know how to just add the latest date into the corresponding column. I want to override the `Stripping_e` value in `Stripping` column if I see `Stripping_f` in the text file. And same for the rest of the columns. It is also the thing that I do not necessarily have a date (expected, started, finished or delayed) for a column.

Here is the code I am currently using:

```
private void IGT_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            table.Columns.Add("SalesNr", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(int));
            table.Columns.Add("Stripping", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Cleaning", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Paint", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Cabinet", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Table", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Stand", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Display", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("User Controls", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Test", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Pre-pack", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("End-pack", typeof(string));
            table.Columns.Add("Release for Delivery", typeof(string));
            dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            Import();
        }

        private void Import()
        {
            // get lines from the text file
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"..\..\567.txt");
            string[] values;


            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
            {
                values = lines[i].ToString().Split(',', '=');
                string[] row = new string[values.Length];

                for (int j = 0; j < values.Length; j++)
                {
                    
                    if(values[j] == "Stripping_e")
                    {
                        row[j] = values[j + 1].Trim();
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if (values[j] == "Stripping_s")
                    {
                        row[j-2] = values[j+1].Trim();
                        j++;
                    }
                    else if(values[j] == "Cleaning_s" || values[j] == "Cleaning_e" || values[j] == "Cleaning_f" || values[j] == "Cleaning_d")
                    {
                        row[j] = values[j + 1].Trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row[j] = values[j].Trim();
                    }
                }
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

`table` is a `DataTable` connected to the `dataGridView1` as `DataSource`.

I have never worked with text files before so I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: @sumit_programmer I saw that you answered a similar question, could you help me with this one?

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? Could you please describe it more specific?

Comment: @dymanoid in my current code i assume that i have expected, started, finished and delayed. According to this assumption i do `j-2` for stripping for example. However, if i do not have `stripping_s` value, then my `cleaning_e` will never be found correctly because will be doing something like `j-3`...

Comment: I need to see a more of the text file.  It looks like you have repeated sections of the file and need to see a few sections to properly write the code.

Comment: @jdweng I edited the example. The phases does not necessarily have to contain a date (this is because we do not know the date yet at the factory) and there also might be delay such as `Cabinet_d=`.

Comment: Using XML format (which is text) is much better than your csv.  Xml is more structured and makes it easier to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading a semi-unstructured CSV can be tricky and you must have a lot of faith in the CSV file always being correct. Example, if one of the dates for a category is misspelled like… “Panint_s=28/05/2020” …  in the posted data… then, in the code below, this misspelling is not going to throw any kind of error or message, it will simply never be used. So, coder beware. Below is one such “hacky” approach.

One complication you may have is how the current code is using string arrays (`string[]`). This is going to make things more complicated. It is useful when the code gets to the point of `SomeCategory=SomeDate`. Below, a string array is used for these splits to get the date for the category. Elsewhere in the code, it uses a `List<string>` to separate the lines in the data. This will help when we want to get the dates for a “particular” category. More below.

So, given a `string` of data as you show, such that the `string` is a “single” row in the grid, then I would “split” that string on commas ”,”. Then convert the string array into a `List<string>`. It may look something like…

```
List<string> SplitRow = curRow.Split(',').ToList();
```

Given the posted single line of data, this `List<string>` `allData` may look something like….

[image]

As can be seen we will use this `List<string>` to get the data for the first three cells in the grid AND when we get to the portion of the code where we want to get the “latest” date for a particular category, we can “filter” this `List<string>` to contain ONLY the categories we want. If `allData` is the `List<string>` above, then to filter the list to contain only the category we want, the code may look something like…

```
String targetCategory = “Stripping”;
List<string> categoryData = allData.Where(x => x.Contains(targetCategory)).ToList();
```

This will produce a `List<string>` `categoryData` with only the “Stripping” categories. Like below…

[image]

With this list we can loop through all the strings, parse the dates and return the latest date from all the given dates. If we create a method that returns this date string, then we can use it to assign each category column in the grid for each row.

Therefore a method, that takes the `allData` list and a `string` category to filter by… may come in handy. This method may look something like below…

```
private string GetLatestDateForCategory(List<string> allData, string targetCategory) {
  List<string> categoryData = allData.Where(x => x.Contains(targetCategory)).ToList();
  DateTime latestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
  string[] splitArray;
  foreach (string catLine in categoryData) {
    splitArray = catLine.Split('=');
    if (splitArray.Length >= 2) {
      if (DateTime.TryParseExact(splitArray[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime date)) {
        if (date > latestDate) {
          latestDate = date;
        }
      } 
    }
  }
  if (latestDate != DateTime.MinValue) {
    return latestDate.ToShortDateString();
  }
  return "";
}
```

A walk through this method would start with “filtering” all the data to get a list of the `targetCategory` string value. Then a `DateTime` variable is created to compare the dates and use as the latest date. We will set the date to a “min” value and we will use this “min” date to indicate that the category has NO dates in the data. Next is the string array `splitArray` which is used to split each string on the “=” character.

A loop through all the filtered strings in the list is started. After splitting the string on the “=” character, a check is made to make sure there is a date in the string. If there is a date string, then that date is parsed to a `DateTime` object for easier comparisons. If the date parses successfully, then the code will check the parsed date to the latest date. If the parsed date is later than the current `latestDate`, then it is updated to reflect this newer latest date.

After all the dates have been checked, the code will check the `latestDate`. If the `latestDate` is still the “Min” value, then that would mean no dates were found for that category and an empty string is returned, otherwise the code will return the latest date string.

If the code loops through each string in the data where there are numerous rows, then the method above will come in handy when we want to get the latest date from a particular category.

So, putting this together may look something like below…

```
private void Import() {
  List<string> allLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\Test\CSV\567.txt").ToList();
  DataRow dr;
  List<string> SplitRow;
  int value;
  foreach (string curRow in allLines) {
    dr = table.NewRow();
    SplitRow = curRow.Split(',').ToList();
    if (SplitRow.Count >= 3) {
      value = 0;
      if (int.TryParse(SplitRow[0], out value)) {
        dr["SalesNr"] = value;
      }
      if (int.TryParse(SplitRow[2], out value)) {
        dr["Type"] = value;
      }
      dr["PName"] = SplitRow[1];
      dr["Stripping"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Stripping");
      dr["Cleaning"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Cleaning");
      dr["Paint"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Paint");
      dr["Cabinet"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Cabinet");
      dr["Table"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Table");
      dr["Stand"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Stand");
      dr["Display"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "Display");
      dr["User Controls"] = GetLatestDateForCategory(SplitRow, "UControls");
      table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
  }
}
```

A walk through this method would start with getting a `List<string>` from the CSV file. In the posted data this would be a single string in the list. Next a `DataRow` `dr` is defined, we will use this row to add the values we get from the data. Another `List<string>` `SplitRow` is used for “each” string in the list. And finally, an `int` `value` which is used to parse the `int` values `SalesNr` and `Type`.

A loop through each string from all the data is started, a new `DataRow` is created from the existing `table`, the current string is then split on a comma “;”. A check is made to make sure there are at least  three (3) values for the SalesNr, PName and Type. The `SalesNr` and `Type` values are parsed, then the `PName` string value is set into the new row. Then, each “category” will use the method above to set the date string for each category. Finally, the row is added to the `table`. Note: not all categories are filled in the code.

I hope this makes sense. Its hacky but it worked in my tests. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication71
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.csv";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(FILENAME);
            string line = "";
            int row = 0;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line = line.Trim();
                if (line.Length > 0)
                {
                    string[] columns = line.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();
                    List<object> newRow = new List<object>(); ;
                    if (++row == 1)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("SalesNr", typeof(string));
                        dt.Columns.Add("PName", typeof(string));
                        dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(int));
                    }
                    for (int col = 0; col < columns.Length; col++)
                    {
                        switch (col)
                        {
                            case 0:
                                newRow.Add(columns[0]);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                newRow.Add(columns[1]);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                newRow.Add(columns[2]);
                                break;
                            default:
                                string[] keyValue = columns[col].Split(new char[] { '=' });
                                if (row == 1)
                                {
                                    dt.Columns.Add(keyValue[0], typeof(DateTime));
                                }
                                if (keyValue[1].Trim().Length > 0)
                                {
                                    newRow.Add(DateTime.ParseExact(keyValue[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    newRow.Add(null);
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(newRow.ToArray());
                }
            }
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
}
```